# C# EF String length Data Validation with POCO property attribute before DB Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework using Database first approach, but I am not using EDMX approach, instead I have my POCO classes defined and in the DBContext I am setting the initializer to NULL. So that it should not try to create objects in the database. Everything working very fine as expected.

In my POCO class I have properties wrapped by the StringLength attribute defined to a maximum length value for that property, just like below.

```
public class Users
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public long? SrNo { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime ScanDateTime { get; set; }
        [StringLength(255)]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(75)]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastlogon")]
        public string LastLogon { get; set; }
        [StringLength(75)]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastlogoff")]
        public string LastLogoff { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1000)]
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "accountinfo")]
        public string AccountInfo { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime DCDTime { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime? LastModDTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using [XmlIgnore] attribute for XML deserialization. I do fill data into this class object by deserializing the XML data. In many of the cases XML may have data for the fields where the length of the data can exceed the StringLength defined in the POCO class.

I want to validate the data before sending a DB insert and getting failed from there.

**I want to check and want to trim the data to the specified length as defined in the StringLength attribute property. For ex, after deserializing the XML data to Users object, if the username exceeds the 75 length then I will trim it to 75 and then pass the complete object for DB insert.**

I know couple of ways of doing this and I am trying one as below by creating Extension method.

```
public static void ValidateData(this List<Users> Data)
{
  int UserNamelength = typeof(Users).GetProperty("UserName ").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false).Cast<StringLengthAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().MaximumLength;
  foreach (var item in Data)
  {
    if (item.UserName.Length > UserNamelength )
    {
    //Trim the UserName field to the length i.e. 75 characters
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly I want the check to be on all the fields for Users class.

**I am looking for any other simple and crisp solution.**

Please help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write custom deserialization code so that truncates the data from the XML into whatever size is specified in the model annotation. This is probably more work but in my opinion cleaner than validation. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am looking for any more specific solution.